# PostgreSql JSONB SELECT against multiple values

Tags: postgresql, json, postgresql-9.4

I have a very simple JSON table which I populate with some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE jsonthings(d JSONB NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO jsonthings VALUES ('{"name":"First","tags":["foo"]}');
INSERT INTO jsonthings VALUES ('{"name":"Second","tags":["foo","bar"]}');
INSERT INTO jsonthings VALUES ('{"name":"Third","tags":["bar","baz"]}');
INSERT INTO jsonthings VALUES ('{"name":"Fourth","tags":["baz"]}');

CREATE INDEX ON jsonthings USING GIN(d);
```

And am attempting to use the index when running a `SELECT`.  A simple `SELECT` to obtain the rows where the value is a single item works just fine:

```
SELECT d FROM jsonthings WHERE d @> '{"name":"First"}';
```

But when attempting to run a query which matches more than one value of `name` I can't find out how to use the index.  I've tried:

```
SELECT d FROM jsonthings WHERE d->>'name' = ANY(ARRAY['First', 'Second']);
SELECT d FROM jsonthings WHERE d->'name' ?| ARRAY['First', 'Second'];
SELECT d FROM jsonthings WHERE d#>'{name}' ?| ARRAY['First','Second'];
```

and all of them show a sequential scan of the table (I'm using `enable_seqscan=false` to force index use if possible).  Is there some way I can rewrite the query so that it uses an index?  I'm aware that I could do:

```
SELECT * FROM jsonthings WHERE d @> '{"name":"First"}' OR d @> '{"name":"Second"}';
```

but then I have a variable-length query and I'm going through JDBC so would then lose the benefits of the query being a PreparedStatement.

I'm also interested in seeing a similar query against any of a number of items in the `tags` key, e.g.:

```
SELECT d FROM jsonthings WHERE d @> '{"tags":["foo"]}' OR d @> '{"tags":["bar"]}';
```

but using an `ARRAY` rather than multiple conditions and using an index.

This is on PostgreSql 9.4.

Comment: You don't have high selectivity. You need around 2-5% data of recordset to enable indexes. Put more records and then maybe your query analyizer will choose index over sequential scan.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I set enable_seqscan to false to force index use so the lack of data isn't the issue.  Although I did add another ten million rows during testing to make sure...

Comment: Please post your explain plan on http://explain.depesz.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From docs (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html)
try to use expression index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_jsonthings_names ON jsonthings USING gin ((d -> 'name'));
SELECT d FROM jsonthings WHERE d @> '{"name": ["First", "Second"]}';
```

Comment: Yeah looks like I do have to use a separate index, which seems odd given that the index obviously exists already and is used in the single-item query.  And the query I need to use is `SELECT d FROM jsonthings WHERE d->'name' ?| ARRAY['First', 'Second'];` otherwise the index is not used.  Thanks.

Comment: @jgm Did you find a more generic way to achieve this? Having separate index per field is inconvenient (and impossible, if dynamic fields are needed).

Answer (score 8):

This is a response to the answer provided by Mladen. I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment, but I wanted to respond because it looks like the query may be incorrect, and was confusing me, and may cause other people to be confused in the future.

You mention using:

```
SELECT d FROM jsonthings WHERE d @> '{"name": ["First", "Second"]}';
```

To retrieve any entries that have either `First` or `Second` as the name, however, this doesn't seem to work for me on `PostgreSQL 9.4.4`:

```
SELECT d FROM jsonthings WHERE d @> '{"name": ["First", "Second"]}';
 d
---
(0 rows)
```

It seems the above query is attempting to retrieve entries where the `name` attribute contains the array `["First", "Second"]`.

If I create such an entry:

```
INSERT INTO jsonthings VALUES ('{"name":["First", "Second"],"tags":["baz"]}');
```

And then try the query again, it returns a result:

```
SELECT d FROM jsonthings WHERE d @> '{"name": ["First", "Second"]}';
d
------------------------------------------------
{"name": ["First", "Second"], "tags": ["baz"]}
(1 row)
```

However, this is different from the question asked by the original poster, which was how to use an index when querying entries where the `name` attribute was either `First` **or** `Second`:

```
SELECT * FROM jsonthings WHERE d @> '{"name":"First"}' OR d @> '{"name":"Second"}';
```

I wanted to provide this here so other people don't think it's possible to perform an **OR** query with JSON by providing `"name": ["First", "Second"]`, since it's misleading.