# Query JSON array of obejcts against multiple values

Tags: postgresql, json, postgresql-9.4, array, json-path

I want to write a query against a `jsonb` type table-column in Postgres that, given an array of customers IDs, will find corresponding groups.

Given this example table:

```
CREATE TABLE grp(d jsonb NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO grp VALUES
   ('{"name":"First","arr":["foo"], "customers":[{"id":"1", "name":"one"},{"id":"2", "name":"two"}]}')
 , ('{"name":"Second","arr":["foo","bar"], "customers":[{"id":"3", "name":"three"},{"id":"4", "name":"four"}]}')
 , ('{"name":"Third","arr":["bar","baz"], "customers":[{"id":"5", "name":"five"},{"id":"6", "name":"seven"}]}');
```

I found similar question ([PostgreSql JSONB SELECT against multiple values](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89971/postgresql-jsonb-select-against-multiple-values)) and managed to achieve what I want on simple array using this query:

```
SELECT d FROM grp WHERE d->'arr' ?| ARRAY['foo', 'bar'];
```

However, I can't make it work when when array contains JSON ***objects***:

```
SELECT d FROM grp WHERE d->'customers' ?| ARRAY['{"id":"1"}', '{"id":"5"}'];
```

Here is what I expect from my query:

grp "First" -> customer "1"

grp "Third" -> customer "5"

Answer (score 36, accepted):

#### Postgres 12 or later

You can use an [SQL/JSON path expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) with the [**`@?`** operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE):

```
SELECT d
FROM   grp
WHERE  d @? '$.customers[*].id ? (@ == "1" || @ == "5")';
```

Note the double quotes: your `id` values are *strings*, not *numbers*.

Or more compact for long lists of values with `like_regex` in the [filter expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-FILTER-EX-TABLE):

```
...
WHERE  d @? '$.customers[*].id ? (@ like_regex "^1|5$")'
```

See:

- [Find rows containing a key in a JSONB array of records](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/196604/find-rows-containing-a-key-in-a-jsonb-array-of-records/196635#196635)
- [Pattern-matching for JSON values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68199288/939860)

#### Any version since Postgres 9.3

There is a way: combine the [containment operator `@>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) with the [`ANY` construct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29245753/939860):

```
...
WHERE  d->'customers' @> ANY (ARRAY ['[{"id":"1"}]', '[{"id":"5"}]']::jsonb[]);
```

Or:

```
...
WHERE d->'customers' @> ANY ('{"[{\"id\": \"1\"}]","[{\"id\": \"5\"}]"}'::jsonb[]);
```

It's essential to cast the array to `jsonb[]` explicitly. And note that each element is a JSON ***array*** containing an object inside like the operator `@>` requires. So it's an array of JSON arrays.

You can use an index for this:

- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18405706/939860)

The [manual explicitly states](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) that the operator `?|` is for ***strings*** matching keys or array elements only (not *values*):

> Do any of the strings in the text array exist as top-level keys or array elements?