# Find rows containing a key in a JSONB array of records

Tags: postgresql, index, json, array, json-path

I'm trying to query for a key present in an array of objects. This structure:

```
column jdata
{"name": "Somedata",
 "array": [ {"name":"bla1", "attr": "somevalue"}, 
            {"name":"bla2", "otherdata": "somevalue2"},
            {"name":"bla3", "otherdata": "somevalue"}
           ],
"otherstuff": "stuff"
}
```

Now I do btree's on `jdata->'name'` or `(jdata->'datetime')::cast` and that works great.

I also do json_path_ops where `jdata->'array' @> '[{"name":"bla3"}]'` works a real charm.

My problem is the `attr` key can be in any of the objects in the array and I care about the record if the key is present, however the value can be nearly anything. Is there a way to query for this? Is there a way it can be indexed? I want to do `jdata->'array' @> '[{"attr": ?}]'` Or maybe the `? 'attr'` can be used inside an array somehow?

Currently I am thinking a trigger that scans for the key and then moves it to a header with a true or false or whatever, and then a normal btree will work. Is there a better way? I need to edit around 500k records at the average site to add this values.

Please point me in a direction.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Postgres 12 or later: with SQL/JSON path expression

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  jdata->'array' @? '$ ? (exists (@."attr"))';
```

You can look for keys or values, only in the outer nesting level or recurse, abstract arrays away (unnest them) in `lax` mode or not (`strict` mode). I added query variations in the fiddle to demonstrate:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=aec2f7ea2be8ab01ac5f2ba5df5696e2)*

**`@?`** is [`jsonpath` existence operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE)

[**`jsonpath`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#DATATYPE-JSONPATH) value `'$ ? (exists (@."attr"))'` explained:

`$` ... look at each value found in left operand (in default "lax" mode)
`?` ... run the following test
`(exists (@."attr"))` ... Does a key with name 'attr' exist?

Can use an **index**, either with default `jsonb_ops`:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_jdata_array_idx ON tbl USING GIN ((jdata->'array'));
```

Or with `jsonb_path_ops`:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_jdata_array_path_ops_idx ON tbl USING GIN ((jdata->'array') jsonb_path_ops);
```

See:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-builtin-opclasses.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING

Related:

- [How to sum the values ​of a json column filtered with regex?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/274273/how-to-sum-the-values-of-a-json-column-filtered-with-regex/274276#274276)

### Any Postgres version with `jsonb` support

That particular use case is not covered by plain indexes for built-in operators.

#### Simple query without index support

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM jsonb_array_elements(jdata->'array') elem
   WHERE  elem ? 'attr' 
   );
```

`EXISTS` because we want each qualifying row *once*, even if multiple array elements can contain the key. And it's faster.
But this query cannot use an index.

#### Expression index

You can generate a text array of unique keys in the given `jsonb` array of records - and wrap the expression into a simple `IMMUTABLE` function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_arr_record_keys(jsonb)
  RETURNS text[] LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
'SELECT ARRAY (
   SELECT DISTINCT k
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements($1) elem, jsonb_object_keys(elem) k
   )';
   
COMMENT ON FUNCTION jsonb_arr_record_keys(jsonb) IS '
   Generates text array of unique keys in jsonb array of records.
   Fails if any array element is not a record!';
```

Then create a GIN expression index based on this function:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_special_idx ON tbl USING gin (jsonb_arr_record_keys(jdata->'array'));
```

Query like this, using the generic array contains operator `@>`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  jsonb_arr_record_keys(jdata->'array') @> '{attr}';
```

Now the index can be used efficiently.

Provide the key name nested in an array (`'{attr}'`). (You can conveniently check for multiple keys this way (`'{attr1, attr2}'`) or similar ... )

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=ad9a3a7c0f49e399d4efc0f933e83a45)*

Related:

- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706)
- [How to get particular object from jsonb array in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127689/how-to-get-particular-object-from-jsonb-array-in-postgresql/127786#127786)
- [Conditionally replace single value per row in jsonb column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53843366/939860)

Comment: @Kobus: Note the update for Postgres 12 or later!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way it can be indexed?

Yes, however PostgreSQL can't JSON arrays like that so you'll have to write a function to simplify the structure. Then you can index on that function.