# jsonb_array_elements() fails with "ERROR: cannot extract elements from an object"

Tags: postgresql, json, jsonb, json-path

Using: Postgres 14.2.
Objective: To get a list of all distinct countries in my table.

The column `address` is a `JSONB` column type and contains an array structured like:

```
{
   "address":[
      {
         "types":["route"],
         "long_name":"20203 113B Ave",
         "short_name":"20203 113B Ave"
      },
      {
         "types":["locality","political"],
         "long_name":"Maple Ridge",
         "short_name":"Maple Ridge"
      },
      {
         "types":["administrative_area_level_3","political"],
         "long_name":"Maple Ridge",
         "short_name":"Maple Ridge"
      },
      {
         "types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"],
         "long_name":"Greater Vancouver",
         "short_name":"Greater Vancouver"
      },
      {
         "types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"],
         "long_name":"British Columbia",
         "short_name":"BC"
      },
      {
         "types":["country","political"],
         "long_name":"Canada",
         "short_name":"CA"
      },
      {
         "types":["postal_code"],
         "long_name":"V2X 0Z1",
         "short_name":"V2X 0Z1"
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I filter this array of objects such that it only returns the value of `"long_name"` (e.g. `Canada`) for the array index if `types` contains `"country"`?

Something like this is what I'm trying but, obviously, I want to return only the country and not the entire brand.

```
SELECT * from brand
where address::text ilike ANY (ARRAY['%country%'::text]);
```

This query fails with:

> ```
> ERROR:  cannot extract elements from an object
> ```

```
SELECT * from brand
where exists (
   select from jsonb_array_elements(address) e
   where (e ->> 'types')::text = 'country'
   );
```

Obviously, this is trivial to do in JS:

```
address.filter((part) => part.types.includes('country'))[0].long_name
```

But I need my db to handle it. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the name suggests, [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) expects a JSON *array* to unnest. But, according to your error message, at least one row contains a `jsonb` value in `address` with a JSON *object* at the top level. (Anything but an array triggers an error.)
Test for the type with [`jsonb_typeof()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) and exclude violating rows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.address ->> 'long_name' AS country_name
FROM  (
    SELECT jsonb_array_elements(b.address) AS address
    FROM   brand b
    WHERE  jsonb_typeof(b.address) = 'array'            -- !!!
   ) x
WHERE  x.address ->> 'types' ILIKE ANY (ARRAY['%country%'::text]);
```

Shorter equivalent:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.adr->>'long_name' AS country_name
FROM   brand b, jsonb_array_elements(b.address) x(adr)
WHERE  jsonb_typeof(b.address) = 'array'
AND    (x.adr->>'types') ~* 'country';
```

**Much** shorter equivalent with [`jsonb_path_query()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE)

```
SELECT DISTINCT jsonb_path_query(address, '$[*] ? (@.types[*] == "country").long_name')
FROM   brand;
```

The raw power of [SQL/JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH), added in Postgres 12. A bit confusing at first, but powerful. Can even use an index. See:

- [Find rows containing a key in a JSONB array of records](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/196604/find-rows-containing-a-key-in-a-jsonb-array-of-records/196635#196635)

And I believe you really wanted to test that `types` array for an exact match on "country" (like your JS code suggests), stricter than your SQL query.

#### The culprit(s)?

You may want to have a closer look at violating rows, if you didn't expect that error ...

```
SELECT * FROM brand
WHERE  jsonb_typeof(address) IS DISTINCT FROM 'array';
```

`null` values are fine. The rest isn't.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ce3934a79ca1c62cf9a980000ca0c231)*

Comment: Well that definitely was the issue! Thank you for the help, Erwin. :) Thank you for explaining the problematic part. makes perfect sense now. Your `IS DISTINCT FROM 'array'` tip also helped me realize that the offending rows are just empty objects. I will make them null instead.

Comment: @bob_cobb: You already accepted, but I think you'll be interested in the bonus track. :)

Comment: Wow that's incredible haha. So glad I decided to migrate to Postgres from MySQL for this project. cheers!

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty trivial in PostgreSQL as well :)

```
select distinct x.addresses->>'long_name' as country_name
from (
    select jsonb_array_elements(t.addresses->'address') as addresses
    from foo t
) x
where x.addresses->>'long_name' ilike any (array['%British Columbia%'])
```

You may see the full code and run it yourself here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/agzPjwiyci5ZS8esWnRH8n/3

Also, you're using `::text` conversion for no reason, the `->>` operator returns a `text` data type. Same with scalar values manually mentioned in a SQL script like your `'%country%'::text`, by default it's already `text`.

Comment: Thank you @Chessbrain. I took your example and updated it since in my db there are a couple of differences. Namely, the address doesn't have an `address` key, and it's an array of objects like this https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/agzPjwiyci5ZS8esWnRH8n/5. When I run this against my production DB, I'm getting the following error: `cannot extract elements from an object`. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: From what I understand based on your example, this should work https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/agzPjwiyci5ZS8esWnRH8n/6 @bob_cobb

Comment: If t his is still throwing errors, then you're not giving us the full picture :) Since it's obviously working on the examples given.

Comment: Heh.. I actually am a bit embarrassed myself here trying to figure out what's wrong. https://imgur.com/wE5ZAto is the table description and an example of an `address` entry, so it's pretty much what I described.