# Add key and value to elements of a jsonb array where the key does not exist yet

Tags: postgresql, update, jsonb, json-path

I have a table `tbl` with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  org  text
, data jsonb
);
```

The data in the `jsonb` field is an array structured in the following way:

```
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
('SOMETHING'
, '[
      {
        "type": "XYZ",
        "valueA": "500",
        "valueB": "ABC"
      },
      {
        "type": "ABC",
        "valueA": "300",
        "valueB": "CDE"
      }
   ]')
;
```

I want to add a key `valueC` to elements of `data` where the object has a `"type"` key with a value of `"XYZ"`.

`valueC`'s value will be an array of strings. The values of the array will depend on the value of the `org` column.

I want to do this for all rows such that if a specific `org` is present, and the `jsonb` array in the `data` column contains an object with `"type": "XYZ"`, then I get this result:

```
[
  {
    "type": "XYZ",
    "valueA": "500",
    "valueB": "ABC",
    "valueC": ["SOMETHING"],
  },
  {
    "type": "ABC",
    "valueA": "300",
    "valueB": "CDE",
  }
]
```

I also want to ensure this script only runs if `valueC` is not present in the object that matches the conditions, so it is not re-run during a migration/rollback unless needed.

Here's what I have so far but it's not working when it does not find a result to the subquery and I can't figure out how to only run this if `valueC` does not exist:

```
UPDATE tbl SET  
  data = jsonb_set(
    data, 
    '{data}', 
   (SELECT jsonb_agg(elem ||'{"valueC":["SOMETHING"]}') FROM jsonb_array_elements(data->'data') as elem where elem ->> 'type' = 'XYZ')
  )
WHERE org = 'SOMETHING';
```

Comment: Show us what you have implemented so far, even if it is not yet working. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Updated the post @J_H

Comment: Well, you already have `jsonb_array_elements(data->'data') as elem where elem ->> 'type' = 'XYZ'`, so you just need to add this to the `where` clause, right?

Comment: The path `'{data}'` you show in the `UPDATE` does not exist in the sample data. Also: Can there be multiple array elements with "type": "XYZ" in a single JSON array? And your version of Postgres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**SQL/JSON path expressions**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#DATATYPE-JSONPATH) make this short and performant. Requires **Postgres 12 or later**:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    data = (SELECT jsonb_agg(CASE WHEN jsonb_path_exists(elem, '$ ? (@.type == "XYZ") ? (!exists (@.valueC))')
                                     THEN elem || '{"valueC":["SOMETHING"]}'
                                     ELSE elem END)
               FROM   jsonb_array_elements(data) AS elem)
WHERE  org = 'SOMETHING'
AND    jsonb_path_exists(data, '$[*] ? (@.type == "XYZ") ? (!exists (@.valueC))')
RETURNING *;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=7b200b8b9d93af661c640f990f67a56e)*

This allows for multiple qualifying array elements to be updated at once.

First, identify qualifying rows cheaply in the `WHERE` clause. (We wouldn't want to process all rows.)

Then, after unnesting with `jsonb_array_elements()`, recheck in a `CASE` expression to only modify qualifying array elements.

If the table is big, be sure to have an **index**. See:

- [Find rows containing a key in a JSONB array of records](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/196604/find-rows-containing-a-key-in-a-jsonb-array-of-records/196635#196635)

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly.