# check if a list of strings in a jsonb contains (or not) an array of strings

Tags: postgresql, json

Given a table **"bgp"."interconnect"**:

#### Query 1

```
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(netelements)) 
FROM (
  SELECT jsonb_object_keys("bgp"."interconnect"."pulse") AS netelements 
  FROM "bgp"."interconnect" 
  WHERE "bgp"."interconnect"."asn" = 7224
) x;
```

returns

```
                   array_to_json                   
---------------------------------------------------
 ["de-fra02a-ri1","nl-ams09c-ri1","uk-lon01b-ri1"]
(1 row)
```

#### Query 2

```
SELECT array_agg(netelements) 
FROM (
  SELECT jsonb_object_keys("bgp"."interconnect"."pulse") AS netelements 
  FROM "bgp"."interconnect" 
  WHERE "bgp"."interconnect"."asn" = 7224
) x;
```

returns

```
                  array_agg                  
---------------------------------------------
 {de-fra02a-ri1,nl-ams09c-ri1,uk-lon01b-ri1}
(1 row)
```

Given a table **"ip"."aws_inet"**:

#### Query 3

```
SELECT "ip"."aws_inet"."pulse"
FROM "ip"."aws_inet"
WHERE "ip"."aws_inet"."service" = 'S3' AND "ip"."aws_inet"."is_ok" IS true
AND "ip"."aws_inet"."metadata" ->> 'region' = 'eu-central-1'
```

returns

```
                        pulse                        
-----------------------------------------------------
 ["de-fra02a-ri1", "nl-ams09c-ri1", "uk-lon01b-ri1"]
 ["de-fra02a-ri1", "nl-ams09c-ri1", "uk-lon01b-ri1"]
 ["de-fra02a-ri1", "nl-ams09c-ri1", "uk-lon01b-ri1"]
 ["de-fra02a-ri1", "nl-ams09c-ri1", "uk-lon01b-ri1"]
 ["de-fra02a-ri1", "nl-ams09c-ri1", "uk-lon01b-ri1"]
 ["de-fra02a-ri1", "nl-ams09c-ri1", "uk-lon01b-ri1"]
 ["de-fra02a-ri1", "nl-ams09c-ri1", "uk-lon01b-ri1"]
 ["de-fra02a-ri1", "nl-ams09c-ri1", "uk-lon01b-ri1"]
 ["de-fra02a-ri1", "nl-ams09c-ri1", "uk-lon01b-ri1"]
 ["de-fra02a-ri1", "nl-ams09c-ri1", "uk-lon01b-ri1"]
 ["de-fra02a-ri1", "nl-ams09c-ri1", "uk-lon01b-ri1"]
(11 rows)
```

I would like to check

- using/against the **reference** result set from the query 1) or 2)
- which strings in `"ip"."aws_inet"."pulse"` jsonb column **do belong** to the  reference result set
- which strings in `"ip"."aws_inet"."pulse"` jsonb column **do not belong** to the reference result set

Can you please advise on how to achieve this?

I have tried (in vain) the following query as a playground (it errors):

```
SELECT  "ip"."aws_inet"."pulse"
FROM    "ip"."aws_inet"
WHERE   "ip"."aws_inet"."service" = 'S3' 
AND     "ip"."aws_inet"."is_ok" IS true
AND     "ip"."aws_inet"."metadata" ->> 'region' = 'eu-central-1'
AND     "ip"."aws_inet"."pulse" ?| ARRAY['nl-ams09c-ri1','uk-lon01b-ri1']
```

**EDIT:** the above works.. it turned out that is a client's problem :(

```
SELECT  "ip"."aws_inet"."pulse"
FROM    "ip"."aws_inet"
WHERE   "ip"."aws_inet"."service" = 'S3' 
AND     "ip"."aws_inet"."is_ok" IS true
AND     "ip"."aws_inet"."metadata" ->> 'region' = 'eu-central-1'
AND     "ip"."aws_inet"."pulse" ?| ARRAY['nl-ams09c-ri1','uk-lon01b-ri1'] ;
                        pulse                        
-----------------------------------------------------
 ["de-fra02a-ri1", "nl-ams09c-ri1", "uk-lon01b-ri1"]
 ["de-fra02a-ri1", "nl-ams09c-ri1", "uk-lon01b-ri1"]
 ["de-fra02a-ri1", "nl-ams09c-ri1", "uk-lon01b-ri1"]
 ["de-fra02a-ri1", "nl-ams09c-ri1", "uk-lon01b-ri1"]
 ["de-fra02a-ri1", "nl-ams09c-ri1", "uk-lon01b-ri1"]
 ["de-fra02a-ri1", "nl-ams09c-ri1", "uk-lon01b-ri1"]
 ["de-fra02a-ri1", "nl-ams09c-ri1", "uk-lon01b-ri1"]
 ["de-fra02a-ri1", "nl-ams09c-ri1", "uk-lon01b-ri1"]
 ["de-fra02a-ri1", "nl-ams09c-ri1", "uk-lon01b-ri1"]
 ["de-fra02a-ri1", "nl-ams09c-ri1", "uk-lon01b-ri1"]
 ["de-fra02a-ri1", "nl-ams09c-ri1", "uk-lon01b-ri1"]
(11 rows)
```

How can I re-write the last query so that I can pass the `SELECT` statement from **query 1** (instead of hard-coding `ARRAY['nl-ams09c-ri1','uk-lon01b-ri1']`) ?
Conceptually, something like this:

```
SELECT  "ip"."aws_inet"."pulse"
FROM    "ip"."aws_inet"
WHERE   "ip"."aws_inet"."service" = 'S3' 
AND     "ip"."aws_inet"."is_ok" IS true
AND     "ip"."aws_inet"."metadata" ->> 'region' = 'eu-central-1'
AND     "ip"."aws_inet"."pulse" ?| SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(netelements)) 
FROM (
  SELECT jsonb_object_keys("bgp"."interconnect"."pulse") AS netelements 
  FROM "bgp"."interconnect" 
  WHERE "bgp"."interconnect"."asn" = 7224
) x;
```

I was inspired by the following articles:

- [PostgreSQL JSON query array against multiple values](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130699/postgresql-json-query-array-against-multiple-values)
- [PostgreSql JSONB SELECT against multiple values](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89971/postgresql-jsonb-select-against-multiple-values)
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925641/check-if-a-postgres-json-array-contains-a-string

Comment: `"ip"."aws_inet"."pulse" ?| ARRAY['nl-ams09c-ri1','uk-lon01b-ri1']` should do what you want (test if the keys are present in the JSON). What is the error you get? And what exactly is the "reference result set"?

Comment: thank you @a_horse_with_no_name for looking into it, it turned out it was the client's problem and the query works. I would appreciate your help in making the query more flexible/dynamic (see EDIT)